# How do I make a message only be sent in a specific category

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying a bit of simple code to make sure a message is only sent in the "main" category of my discord server. When I try doing that, every time I send something on any category it tells me that the category is not allowed. I am also not getting any errors. CODE BELOW:

```
if(message.channel.Parent !== `Ticket Category ID`) return message.channel.send(`Open A Ticket To Use This Command!`);
```

If you have any Idea.. Please Tell me as help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `message.channel.parentID !== 'id'`

Answer (score 0):

You want to be getting the parents name instead of the parent object as a whole:

```js
if(message.channel.parent.id !== `Ticket Category ID`) return message.channel.send(`Open A Ticket To Use This Command!`);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this may have just been a typo, but JavaScript variables are case-sensitive, and `parent` should be lowercase.

[TextChannel#parent](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=parent) gives you the category as a `CategoryChannel`, not a string/id, so if you compare it directly to the channel name it will always not be equal. Instead, you're looking for the [TextChannel#parentID](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CategoryChannel?scrollTo=parentID), which gives you the id of the channel:

```
if(message.channel.parentID !== `Ticket Category ID`) return message.channel.send(`Open A Ticket To Use This Command!`);
```